# How to Add service reference of type "gRPC" to a project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, grpc, connected-services

I have two projects in a Visual Studio Solution.

- Project 1 implements a gRpc server endpoint. On the gRpc server reflection is enabled
- Project 2 Is a client project that should consume the gRpc endpoint exposed by the gRpc server project.

I want to reference project 1 as a "Connected service" from project 2. So when a DataContract of the gRpc service changes I will be able to update the "service reference" and the client stubs that communicate with the gRpc server will be regenerated.

I try to configure the client project and add a "Connected service". In the "Add service reference" dialog I choose to add a service of type "gRPC". After clicking the "Next" button I provide the url to the reflection endpoint of my running grpc server. (https://localhost:portnumber/grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo)

After clicking the finish button I receive an error message "Failed to download metadata file from : https://localhost:portnumber/grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo"
In the logging info on my grpc server I see and error message "Request content-type of '(null)' is not supported".

**What does Visual Studio expect as input to configure a gRpc connected service?**

Note: I have tested my gRpc server with Postman and dotnet-grpc-cli. Endpoints and contracts are correctly discovered and can be invoked using the Postman UI.

Comment: The error message `Request content-type of '(null)' is not supported` suggests that the request sent to your gRPC server does not contain a valid Content-Type header. You probably have a wrong client config. Judging from the `https` in your error message and the way you described how you used the "Add service reference", I would assume that you have not configured TLS at all on the client side, which could be your problem. I have never used the GUI to add a service reference, so I cannot tell, and you do not provide any client code. But maybe this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I have no client config at all. I am trying to use the "Add connected service" feature in a .net core 8.0 project in Visual Studio. The client project is just an empty commandline type project without any code. The Visual Studio dialog just gives me an option to enter an url...

Comment: I haven't tried it out, but if you use the "Add connected service" feature, it creates [JSON files with your configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/overview-connected-services?view=vs-2022#how-it-works).

Comment: It will probably also create a C# class for the client endpoint (can be found in the `obj` folder I think, at least there it is when you connect to a REST service with "Add connected services"). Inside that C# class, it probably contains code that [looks something like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#call-grpc-services-with-a-net-client)

Comment: I would look at that generated code and the JSON configs, and try to figure out what is wrong. As I said previously, I would assume that at least the TLS encryption is wrong, since that requires special setup.

Comment: These are just recommendations on how I would debug your problem, hope it helps. All I can tell from this question is that (probably) generated client-side code for your gRPC service is either wrong or wrongly configured.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. Yes with the OpenApi option using a swagger.json file it works and I get generated code that I can inspect in the obj folder. But the gRPC option doesn't generate anything since the discovery phase is already throwing an exception. I added additional log statements to my grpc server to see what the differences are between Postman calling my reflection endpoint and Visual Studio. The logging shows that Visual Studio is calling the reflection endpoint with a GET request instead of POST. So I think the Visual Studio implementation is simply wrong

Comment: Ah dang :/ Guess then you have to take the manual approach. Or maybe somebody on SO had a similar issue and sees your question..

Comment: I have already solved the issue by implementing a http GET endpoint on my grpc server that returns a .proto file response. Now I am able to provide Visual Studio with a url that points to a valid .proto file. If the server implementation changes I am able to use the "refresh" option to newly download the .proto file and update the client stub code. Exactly how it is supposed to work (Like in the WCF days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
The Url that is used in the "Add gRPC connected service" dialog needs to point to a http GET endpoint that returns a .proto file. Not as I expected a url to a grpc reflection endpoint.

Thanks Microsoft for the missing documentation....